# C#, NetCore 3.0 - Method : [HttpGet]

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have a problem with retrieving data from an array for a specific user - there are many users in the array, I want to retrieve data for one specified in label1.Text
So - the first:

```
public async Task load_data()
        {              
            var doing = await client.GetAllAsync(label1.Text);
            foreach (var dane in doing )
            {
                lbItems_1.Items.Add(dane.Name);
                lbItems_2.Items.Add(dane.Age);
                lbItems_3.Items.Add(dane.Data);
            }
        }
```

Next : GetAllAsync()

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Table_test>> GetAllAsync(string user_name)
{
var response = await client.GetAsync(_baseUrl + "/api/user/" + user_name);
}
```

And the last class:

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string user_name)
        {
            using (var c = new MySqlConnection(con_sql.MySQL))
            {
                var sql = @"SELECT * FROM table_test WHERE username = @username";
                var query = c.Query<Models.Table_test >(sql, new { username = user_name}, commandTimeout: 30);                
                return Ok(query);
            }
        }
```

I think it passes the parameter well - however when I try to download data for the appropriate user I have: NotFound code

Why? Ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: All this files are on the same project?

Comment: What is `NotFound code` ?

Comment: @LuttiCoelho - Yeah, all of them.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen - The compiler says the problem is : var doing = await client.GetAllAsync(label1.Text); Nothing more.

Comment: I will add that downloading all data or deleting all data works - but it does not work for the selected user.

Comment: _baseUrl is the same url of your project? Are you calling a controller from another controller?

Comment: @LuttiCoelho - Yes, the same. I've problem only with load a data for the selected user (label1.Text) - other processes like download for everyone and delete for everyone works.

Comment: Why are you calling a Controller from other Controller using HTTP call? I can't imagine a good reason for that?

Comment: Ca you update your question with more information about your solution architecture? It will help you to get an answer fast.

Comment: So how is it better to do it?

Comment: Ok - so: all commands work - but if I want to get data from an array for a specific user, there is a problem even though it passes the parameter correctly.

Comment: Put your query in a class that is accessible by both controllers, and both controllers can call it without use a self http call.

Comment: Ok - it's done - I added [HttpGet("{user_name}")] and it's proccess fine.

Comment: Great that It solve your problem. But if both methods are in the project. You still have a architecture problem that can cause you more trouble in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to specify the route parameter on the endpoint in the `HttpGet` attribute:

```
[HttpGet("{user_name}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string user_name) 
{ 
    using (var c = new MySqlConnection(con_sql.MySQL)) 
    { 
        var sql = @"SELECT * FROM table_test WHERE username = @username"; 
        var query = c.Query<Models.Table_test >(sql, new { username = user_name}, commandTimeout: 30); 
        return Ok(query); 
    } 
}
```

---

Another option would be to call the endpoint using a query parameter:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Table_test>> GetAllAsync(string user_name) 
{ 
    var response = await client.GetAsync(_baseUrl + "/api/user?user_name=" + user_name); 
}
```

Comment: And if I want to add two WHERE conditions, can I define the Route path twice for two different parameters?

Comment: Yes, just keep in mind that parameters defined in the route (in the `HttpGet` attribute) are required. If you want the conditions to be optional you should probably use query parameters

Comment: Ok - if I have a problem I will answer you, thank you!